# In propel getId() returns NULL after save()

Tags: symfony, orm, propel

I have some tables defined in schema.xml which work just fine. The models for them were generated in Propel 1.2. XML entries look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="..." namespace="..." defaultIdMethod="native">
<table name="book">
    <vendor type="mysql">
        <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
        <parameter name="Charset" value="utf8"/>
    </vendor>
    <column name="id"
            type="bigint"
            required="true"
            primaryKey="true"
            autoIncrement="true"
            />
   ...some other columns here...
</table>
...some other tables...
</database>
```

Now, I add the following entry and generate model for it in Propel 1.4:

```
<table name="file">
...vendor...
<column name="id"
        type="bigint"
        required="true"
        primaryKey="true"
        autoIncrement="true"
        />
...other columns...
</table>
```

The problem is that after I create such object and do `$file->save()`, `$file->getId()` returns NULL. Other models, like the abovementioned `Book`, work like a charm.
Also, I can see that BaseFile does not have `setId()` call in its `doInsert` method, whereas BaseBook  does, as well as other models.

I would appreciate if someone explained what can cause such behavior.

Comment: Did You try to rebuild your model using propel command ?

Comment: @skowron-line: Actually, after reading your comment I ran propel:model:build a couple times more with admin rights, and now it generated everything properly, with `setId()` in `doInsert()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you - your solution helped me (:

My solution:
My schema was built when the problematical table hadn't got primary key on id column. After fixing this in DB I didn't apply changes in schema.xml. Just add

```
 primaryKey="true"
```

in id column in schema.xml so it is like

```
<column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
```

and rebuild classes using terminal.